# Correct way to convey "reducing" a trade-off

Tags: modifiers

I am writing a scientific paper. In my field, there is typically a trade-off between the robustness and speed of an algorithm. I have developed an algorithm where the trade-off isn't as bad as in existing techniques, but I'm looking for a formal way of conveying this. The phrases "reduces the trade-off" or "alleviates the trade-off" are the best I can think of, but they don't seem right. I also thought of "weakens the trade-off" which conveys the point, but still seems wrong. Is there a weaker form of "breaks the trade-off" that can be used in this situation?

Comment: Closes the trade-off gap.

Comment: _readjusts_ the trade-off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are *improving* the trade-off.

In your case your algorithm improves the process, that is, makes the trade-off a better deal. You are improving the trade-off. You are getting more of what you want, the results, while giving up less, or costing less (of your resources) than before. Think of the ratio. You were getting 60% for the cost of 40%, but now you get 75% for the cost of 25%.

Answer (score 1):

You could say that the technique or your solution *results in a better trade-off*.

Example:
"*One of the challenging areas in dealing with Non-Functional Requirements (NFRs) is the need for a decision support system which helps in a better trade-off among alternative operationalizations in the potential solution space for the NFRs.*"
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6577705

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).